# MS Access SQL Query merging two different fields from separate tables shows reference ID's instead of actual values

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two separate tables in my access database, which both use a third table as the reference for one particular field on each table. The data is entered onto the different tables by separate forms. Then I have several queries that then reference those particular fields that count and show unique values. Those queries show the actual values, then I created an sql query that does the same thing, only it shows the reference ID instead of the value in the actual field.

table ODI----------table CDN----------reference table
 id   RHA---------id CHA----------------id  HA
  1 blank----------1 radio---------------1 internet
  2 internet-------2 tv------------------2 radio
  3 referral-------3 radio---------------3 referral
  4 tv-------------4 blank---------------4 repeat customer
  5 blank----------5 internet------------5 tv
  6 internet-------6 referral------------6 employee
  7 referral-------7 referral------------7 social media

this is the code I am trying to make work.

```
SELECT m.[Marketing Results], Count(*) AS [Count]
 FROM (SELECT RHA as [Marketing Results] FROM ODI
  UNION ALL
  SELECT CHA as [Marketing Results] FROM CDN)  AS m
 GROUP BY m.[Marketing Results]
 HAVING (((m.[Marketing Results]) Is Not Null))
 ORDER BY Count(*) DESC;
```

and what my desired result is,

Marketing Results--Counts
  referral------------------4
  internet------------------3
  radio---------------------2
  tv------------------------2

Comment: BTW, placing your tables side-by-side in question was just confusing.

Answer (score 2):

Lookup fields with alias don't show what is actually stored in table. ID is stored, not descriptive alias. Lookup alias will carry into regular queries but Union query only pulls actual stored values. At some point need to include reference table in query by joining on key fields in order to retrieve descriptive alias. Options:

1. in each UNION query SELECT line, join tables
2. join UNION query to reference table
3. join aggregate query to reference table

Most experienced developers will not build lookups in table because of confusion they cause. Also, they are not portable to other database platforms. http://access.mvps.org/Access/lookupfields.htm

Comment: Any chance you could give me a start on option 1 or 2?  I am trying to understand the inner join, while also still learning ms access.

Comment: What exactly do you not understand? If typing SELECT statement with JOIN clause is a challenge, use query designer to build.

Comment: Nevermind, after i finished bashing my head, I went to the reports I use to actually show the data, and they are showing the information correctly.  Needless to say, I was working myself up for no reason.  Thank you for your help, as I learned a very valuable lesson, just because a query shows one thing, the more important report was showing exactly as I desired.